# sign in with facebook swift error

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase-authentication

I am trying to do Sign In with Facebook/Firebase Swift authentication, and I'm at the point where there's a functioning button. I am trying to run something that performs a segue once the login is complete, but I have not been successful in my tries.

```
func viewDidLoad(){
    let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile, .email])
    loginButton.center = view.center

    view.addSubview(loginButton)

    if let accessToken = AccessToken.current {
        print("signed in")
    }

}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: LoginButton){
    print("logged out of fb")

}

func loginButton(_ loginButton: LoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: LoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }
```

Comment: what error its giving can please elaborate more

Comment: @Optimus its not that im getting an error, moreso that once the user authenticates with facebook and theres a blank screen(webview) with the done button i have not been able to find out how to call a segue, collect data etc

Comment: You need to add have the callback of facebook in appDelegate
eg.
   func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let facebookUrl = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
 
        return  facebookUrl 
          
    }

Comment: @Optimus what does that do

Comment: It's will make call back to your application. When user authenticate from facebook